# MYSQL trigger to insert data into a row. based upon some criteria

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables

**purchase_master**

```
+--------+---------+------------+
| autoid | user_id | package_id |
+--------+---------+------------+
```

**user_master**

```
+--------+---------+------+------------+-----------+
| autoid | user_id | name | user_email | user_pass |
+--------+---------+------+------------+-----------+
```

**package_master**

```
+-------------+----------+--------------+-----------+------------+---------------+------------+
| poster_path | overview | release_date | genre_ids | package_id | original_title| **isfree** |
+-------------+----------+--------------+-----------+------------+---------------+------------+
```

I want that whenever a new row is created into `user_master`, a trigger should fire that gets all rows in `package_master` where `isfree = true`, and populate those records along with `new user_master.user_id` into `purchase_master` table.

Example
lets say package_master has 2 rows having package_id = 100 & package_id = 101, in which *isfree=true* so when a new record is created into user_master having user_id = C601, the purchase_master table should have 2 new entries like.

```
"autoid" = 10,"user_id"=C601,"package_id"=100
"autoid" = 11,"user_id"=C601,"package_id"=101
```

Please guide me if it is possible through mysql trigger. Else I have to do it in PHP, on form submission.

EDIT:: I am using phpmyadmin

Comment: It is possible...

Comment: Can you please give me some clue, I am new to mysql, basically a frontend developer.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER bi_user_master BEFORE INSERT ON user_master
  INSERT INTO purchase_master (user_id, package_id)
    SELECT NEW.user_id, pm.package_id
      FROM package_master AS pm
      WHERE isfree;
```

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin